# Search database using array and then echo/print result in foreach loop using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, foreach

I need to get variable `code` from URL so I `$codes = $_GET['code'];` (url example `website.com/update?code[]=7291&code[]=9274&code[]=8264&`) then I `SELECT firstname FROM guests WHERE invitecode = $codes"` then I output data and set as `$relatives = $row["firstname"]` and then later on in the file I need to echo/print `print $relative`.

Why is this not working for me?

```
... connection made ...
$codes = $_GET['code'];
$sql = "SELECT firstname FROM guests WHERE invitecode = $codes";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $relatives[] = $row["firstname"];
}
}

foreach ($relatives as $relative) {
print $relative;
}
```

**Update:**

So now using:

```
<?php

$codes = $_GET['code'];
$thecodes = "";
foreach($codes as $vals)
    $thecodes .= (int)$vals . ",";
if($thecodes != "")
{
    $thecodes = trim($thecodes, ",");
    $sql = "SELECT firstname FROM guests WHERE invitecode IN ($thecodes)";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $relatives[] = $row["firstname"];
}
}
foreach ($relatives as $relative) {
print $relative;
}
}
else
{
}

?>
```

It works but I would like to enter the `foreach ($relatives as $relative) { echo $relative; };` into a value like this `$message = $firstname . " " . $lastname . " will be coming to your event. " . ;`.

In the end it would turn out something like this: `$message = $firstname . " " . $lastname . " will be coming to your event. " . foreach ($relatives as $relative) { echo $relative . " "; };`.

For some reason it won't work when I combine them.

Comment: Please use proper handling of user controlled variables when inserting them into an SQL statement: [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I'd *HIGHLY* advise against just doing a separate query for each code within a loop. That's ridiculously inefficient. It's quite easy to just build a `WHERE` clause and then use one query, then use PHP to structure it out how you want. In any case, a query within a `foreach` is an insanely terrible idea. There is no case I'd ever say that is acceptable unless it's a personal project where no one else will ever have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `IN` operator for this.

```
<?php

$codes = $_GET['code'];
$thecodes = "";
foreach($codes as $vals)
    $thecodes .= (int)$vals . ","; //Loop through making sure each is an int for security reasons (No sqli)
if($thecodes != "") //There is at least one code
{
    $thecodes = trim($thecodes, ","); //Remove any additional commas
    $sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM guests WHERE invitecode IN ($thecodes)"; //Use the IN operator
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["lastname"] . "is coming to your event";
        }
    }

}
else //No codes to be queried
{

}

?>
```

Comment: Your example works, but if you check my update on the post above.  I can't seem to print the `$relatives` anywhere I want. I need it inside this stament: `$message = $firstname . " " . $lastname . " will be coming to your event. " . ;` please see my example above. Thanks.

Comment: Updated it, would you like something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Can this be a solution for you?

```
$relatives = array(); // declare array
$codes = $_GET['code'];
$sql = "SELECT firstname FROM guests WHERE ";
foreach ($codes as $code) $sql .= "invitecode = " . intval($code) . " OR ";
$sql .= "1=2"; // simple way to remove last OR or to make sql valid if there are no codes
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      array_push($relatives, $row["firstname"]);
  }
}

foreach ($relatives as $relative) {
print $relative;
}
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please escape your input.

Comment: @Adriano your example works but I will use Matt's because he shows it with `IN`  Please see my update

Comment: @Matt You're right. I changed the code so that the codes are converted to integers. Your solution is also much more elegant than my ;)

Comment: @user3263981 I didn't solved only the codes problem, I solved also your question about the firstname array! You have to declare $relatives as array and then you can add more usernames with array_push.

Comment: @Adriano yes that's what Matt showed.  And it works, but if you check my update on the post above.  I can't seem to print the `$relatives` anywhere I want. I need it inside this stament: `$message = $firstname . " " . $lastname . " will be coming to your event. " . ;` please see my example above.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work...

```
... connection made ...
$codes = $_GET['code'];
$sql = "SELECT firstname FROM guests WHERE invitecode = '$codes'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('-1' . mysqli_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo ($row['firstname']);
}
}
```